# My 2014 Nissan versa won't start click in the interior lights does not come on

Tags: engine, starting, nissan, stall, versa

Just trying to figure out why my 2014 Nissan versa won't start. It won't click. The interior lights will not come on. One day coming from the grocery store at a red light my car started jerking doing weird stuff and all of a sudden it just shut off completely. I want to say that it's a CVT recall but before taking it to the shop and paying all this money I just want to know could it be the battery? It won't start it won't make a click it there's no lights on the dashboard someone if you know please help me. I don't know anything about cars.

Comment: Sure sounds like a battery problem to me.  Either the battery is too old and can't hold a charge anymore, or the alternator is bad and it stopped charging the battery.

Comment: Could also check that you still have a serpentine belt

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the battery is dead. Look for a couple things:
Are the battery terminal in good condition, and connected tightly? They should be clean and tight. For the car to stop mid-driving like that, I'd suspect the earth/ground terminal.
The alternator is the battery charger, so if it had a failure, you'd normally get a warning light before a full shutdown.

Definitely not a CVT issue, because 'no lights, no click' is electrical.

And, BTW, 24 year old female doesn't mean anything negative at all, don't beat on yourself!